# In Kenobi (Episode V), how was the lightsaber still working?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

Since Vader cut the lightsaber in half, why was the Third Sister able to hold on to her ***complete*** inquisitorial lightsaber after being stabbed? Is there some sort of plot armor going on?

Sorry there’s no pictures or time cuts. Was watching Kenobi with family and couldn’t find the pictures online.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vader never cuts the lightsaber in two, he merely separates the two halves of it. The [Inquisitor lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Double-bladed_spinning_lightsaber) that the Third Sister uses is very similar to the one that Sixth Brother also uses; both them are [split sabers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Split_saber) i.e. the two halves of the double lightsaber can be used independently of each other or joined together. You can see Vader doing this at roughly 47 seconds into the below video: